# Windows Power Plan automation

Tags: windows, laptop, powershell, automation, power-management

I like to keep my Asus ROG G750JZ(laptop) on all the time and I have already automated sleeping at 01:00 in the morning, auto wake-up on opening the lid. However since I am not using the laptop all the time and I keep the lid down to save energy, I would like to maximize the energy saving further by automatically switching the power plan from balanced to power saving (actually ASUS's Power4Gear Power Saving) on closing the lid.

Now I did a lot of research on this topic, unfortunately I could not find anything that does what I need. The closest I found was Power Plan Assistant(http://www.powerplan7.com/home.htm), but it doesn't offer the desired features. I found a few topics about powercfg command using powershell, but I could not understand them. I am open to suggestions and I am also willing to automate this by writing a script in powershell as well.

OS: Windows 8.1

Edit: I don't want it to go to sleep, as i would like to access it remotely few times a day.

Comment: Just configure it to go to sleep when you close the lid. Power plans don't matter when it's sleeping, it's disabling everything it can anyway.

Comment: I do not want it to go to sleep, as I access it remotely. Sorry for not mentioning this in the question.

Comment: You should edit your question, that's quite important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered this question before, so your research could've been better.

You can simply change the powerplan from the commandline, and because that is possible, you can also change it using a scheduled task.

Here is how:

1. Open a commandprompt window
2. Type in: `powercfg -l`
3. Rightclick in the window, and select `mark`.
4. Use the mouse, to select the entire GUID number for the powerscheme you want to set. (It'll look like: `12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890abc`)
5. After the entire GUID is selected, right click. (this will copy the text to the clipboard.)
6. Make a task or edit an existing one in the task scheduler and give it the following program with parameters:

{Guid} is that long number you copied:

```
 powercfg -setactive {Guid}
```

Just to clarify, the program is `powercfg`, the parameters are `-setactive {Guid}`

Comment: Thank you for your input. I could not find closing lid as a trigger in the task scheduler, however I was able to work it out by setting the trigger to "on workstation lock", which I though was good enough as I lock my laptop anyway before closing the lid. Therefore I marked your answer as the answer.

Comment: By what you written in your post, it seemed like you already got that part covered. Thats why I didn't mention about locking and unlocking from the task scheduler, which is what I use myself. I stop using my pc, I lock it, task scheduler sets my poweroptions, I start using it, I unlock it, it switches back.

Comment: I mentioned auto-wake up on opening the lid, that is a bios feature, not through task scheduler(only sleeping at 01:00 is done using task scheduler). Unfortunately my laptop doesn't have wake on alarm feature in bios, to automate wake up using task scheduler. But this solution is good enough. I wrote two scripts to change powerplan on lock and unlock. Thank you very much for your answer, it helped a lot. :)

Comment: You're welcome. :) Just for your clarification, you can lock windows using WIN+L, and using the powerscheme options, you can instantly dim the screen, putting the backlight off. It'll look like the pc is going to sleep while it runs on very low power, doing everything it normally does. I made my main pc go from 250+ wattage to 50 wattage in this mode when locking my pc, keeping my programs and tasks (such as downloading) running.

Comment: The only point I had to fix was that if the computer keeps running, windows update may reboot your pc bringing it to an unlocked state. But you can program something to lock your pc at startup.

Comment: Yes, I know the shortcut. My laptop is a 4th gen core i7, so pretty low power usage by default and when I switch to the ASUS designed power saver mode, it under-clocks and under-volts the cpu and the power is reduced from a 10.75 Watts to 2-4 Watts. It also uses the Nvidia optimus setting, so gpu is mostly powered off all the time. But your comment inspired me to research more about this and further  decrease the power usage(although highly improbable, it can't go any lower than this, but you never know) and make my machine more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning shortcut keys for Power Control:

- Create two batch files, Screen-off.bat and Screen-on.bat.
- In each one put the applicable "`powercfg -setactive {guid}`" command.
- Create shortcuts to these two *.bat files on the desktop.
- Using properties, create shortcut keys for these two files, e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.
- To activate either batch file, use the shortcut keys or else double-click the shortcut icon.

Comment: Great tip on the shortcut. I'll definitely use it on my other projects. However for my current problem, using task scheduler was a better solution. Thank you!